# why does JMeter create so many threads in a load test?

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, out-of-memory, load-testing

I have a number JMeter tests that all run from the command line at the same time.
These have the number of users passed in as a property file (users_concurrent.properties).

For instance:

```
C:/applications/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.bat -n -t RDA_CAEventMaintenance.jmx -l UK_RDA_CAEventMaintenance.jtl -q dev_uk.properties -q users_concurrent.properties
```

For most of these tests, this runs 5 test threads (verified in both results file and thread dumps).
However 2 of these tests ran out of memory and created hprof.pid dump files.

Analysing these files shows what appears to be ~100 threads taking up the over half the heap:
[image]

Is this a JMeter bug? It shouldn't be starting that many threads when I specify 5.

Using JMeter 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Looking into

> Thread Group 1 - 100

it seems you have at least 100 threads. You can double check it in *jmeter.log* file, look for the line like:

> Starting thread group... number=1 threads=XXX

So you either define or refer the property which stands for the number of threads in the wrong way. Example correct configuration would be:

1. Under JMeter Thread Group define number of virtual users using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```
2. Make sure your `users_concurrent.properties` file contains the following line (and the line appears only once)

   ```
   threads=5
   ```

Also just in case make sure you are following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)